p4: how to add link to external folder
Suppose that I have a large 3rd party source folder that I want to add to p4. If I directly add the folder to p4 via 'p4 add', p4 GUI will no longer function normally. It says "the selected Workspace folder has more than 1000000 depot files".
I want to remove this from p4 and add it as symbolic links to external folder. How do I do this?
Suppose that I store this folder as /3rdparty/foo.  My workspace folder is /p4_client_name/3rdparty. if I create a symbolic link to /3rdparty/foo under /p4_client_name/3rdparty, I cannot add /p4_client_name/3rdparty/foo to p4. p4 does not allow adding a symbolic link to absolute path. you can only add a symbolic link to relative path that exists in the depot already.
The only way around this that I can see is to change my p4 source code to refer to /3rdparty/foo explicitly, e.g. -I/3rdparty/foo, rather than through relative path -I../foo.
Thanks.

Is this a flat folder with more than 1000000 files at a single level?  Or a large folder that contains that many files nested under directories?  P4V might have trouble expanding a giant flat folder like that but I wouldn't think it'd have trouble with a more normally structured large folder.
